# Google authorization as a Service Account (Java)

Tags: java, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to get authorization through a Service Account to Google Sheets (No confirmation window). I can't find any information about it. If I use the method from https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java then I get an Error `IllegalArgumentException.`
The general method I use :

```
// Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
        .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
        .setAccessType("offline")
        .build();
    LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
```

A credentials file

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "mytestproject-2",
  "private_key_id": "****",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n***0=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "test@mytestproject-2.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "001",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/test%40mytestproject-2.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

I found information about the implementation through Python
`credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(CREDENTIALS_FILE, ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']),` but can't find any information with Java (similar methods).

Comment: check the service account example for google analytics.   https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/service-java    see if this doesn't help you figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
 /**
   * Initializes an Sheets API V4 service object.
   *
   * @return An authorized Sheets API V4 service object.
   * @throws IOException
   * @throws GeneralSecurityException
   */
  private static Sheets initializeSheets() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential
        .fromStream(new FileInputStream(KEY_FILE_LOCATION))
        .createScoped(AnalyticsReportingScopes.all());

    // Construct the Sheets service object.
    return new Sheets.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
        .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
  }
```